# Определение порядкового номера элемента

Tags: javascript, jquery

Делаю JS-редактор страницы. Нужно узнать порядковый номер элемента, по которому кликнули (для jQuery это `:eq(num)`).

Элемент, по которому кликнули, определяю так:

```
$(document).on('click', 'body,body *', function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault();
    alert('Клик был на элементе ' + e.target.tagName);
});
```

Нужно узнать всю очередь элементов и их порядковые номера для того, чтобы потом обращаться к ним с помощью jQuery:

```
$('body тэг1:eq(номер_тега1) тэг2:eq(номер_тега2) тэг3:eq(номер тега3)')
```

Как это сделать?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Операция, обратная `:eq` - это [`.index()`](https://api.jquery.com/index/). `index` позволяет получить порядковый номер конкретного элемента для какого-то селектора. Т.е. тот самый номер, который можно дописать в `:eq` в селекторе и получить именно этот элемент.

```js
$(document).on('click', 'body,body *', function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
  e.preventDefault();
  // результаты во внедренном коде не будут начинатся с 0
  // где-то на самой странице есть еще 2 li + сам тэг body
  // попробуйте заменить селекторы на `ul.test li` - тогда индексы будут начиная 0
  alert('Клик был на элементе ' + $('body,body *').index(e.target));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="test">
  <li>click me 1</li>
  <li>click me 2</li>
  <li>click me 3</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: нет, мне нужно узнать порядковый номер относительно родительского элемента (ul). Т.е. в данном примере там где **<li>click me 1</li>** должен быть алерт "0", независимо от того сколько li-элементов на странице. Причем родительский элемент неизвестен

Comment: @Ивашка ну тогда просто `$(this).index()`. или `$(e.target).index()` - это одно и то же

Answer (score 0):

Достаточно сохранять кликнутые элементы. Например, в массиве:

```js
var clickedElements = [];
$(document).on('click', '*', function() {
    if (clickedElements.indexOf(this) == -1) {
        clickedElements.push(this);
    }
    $(clickedElements).css('background-color', 'green');
    return false;
});
```

```css
span {
    display: block;
}
td {
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <p>paragraph</p>
    <span>span</span>
    div itself
</div>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>4</td>
    </tr>
</table>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```